# Updating DataTables page dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a server side datatable setup. I'm trying to set the datatable page, when hashchange event is triggered like this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange',function(){ 
    $("#loans").dataTable().fnSettings().displayStart = 100;

    console.log( 'Offset: ' +       $("#loans").dataTable().fnSettings().displayStart );

    $("#loans").dataTable().fnDraw();
});
```

The problem is that `fnDraw()` reloads the whole table and ignores the displayStart argument. If I write `fnDraw(false)`, it doesn't work ether. I need to dynamically set page number and then reload the table (and make it pass the new offset to ajax call URL), but instead it's requesting the offset at 0 not at 100. How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: What DataTables version are you using: 1.9 or 1.10?

Answer (score 3):

For DataTables 1.9 you can use [`fnPageChange()`](http://legacy.datatables.net/api#fnPageChange) API method to change page and redraw the table:

```
$('#loans').dataTable().fnPageChange(10);
```

For DataTables 1.10 you can use [`page()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29) API method to change page and redraw the table:

```
$('#loans').DataTable().page(10).draw('page');
```